# Requirement on processor and memory for image processing

Tags: camera

I'm designing a camera system to use a 5MP CMOS image sensor with a micro controller board. In order to select proper components I'm looking for some numbers. It would be very appreciated if you give me advices.

The question is this. If I take a picture with resolution of 2592 x 1944, frame rate of 1 fps and the format of image data is 32 bit RGB, then how fast cpu and how large memory would you need? When I calculated the bitrate, it's like the followings

1. data size of one frame
   number of pixel = 2592 x 1944 = 5,038,848 
   data size of one frame = 32 bit x 5,038,848 = 161,243,136 bit = 157,464 byte
   (And I confirmed this size with raspberry pi camera)
2. data transfer 
   Now I need to transfer the frame data to my flash memory. But I would take just one cut with long exposure time. In other words, I don't need to take 2 or 3 pictures for short time. It would be enough to take just 1 image for 1 hour. Let's say I take 1 picture for 1 seconds and don't take any pictures anymore. Then,

bitrate = 161,243,136 bit/s = 157,464 byte/s = 15.4MB/s

But I can't go ahead with this number. Does it mean that I need a RAM larger than 15.4MB to save the frame for a moment? Or is it possible to use 2MB to transfer the data to hard disk or some storage, even it's slow? I couldn't find any information by googling.

In addition, I wonder how fast processor I need. For example, do I need 200MHz processor? or is it enough to have 15MHz processor like arduino? I have no idea. Please help me.

Comment: 2592*1944*32 = 161243136 bits is 20155392 8-bit bytes (around 20 MB).  If you want to minimize the chance of image tearing then you will want over 20 MB to read out a full frame in one contiguous image capture.

Comment: JPEG compression in software takes very roughly on the order of a hundred to a few thousands of CPU cycles per pixel (depending on the processor and memory characteristics of the system,compression ratio, etc.).  So a GHz processor may be required if you want to store a JPEG compressed version of the a 5 mega-pixel image around once per second.